# How to give permission to tthe user to access the file when only i want

Tags: php, file

i have a zip file and user can only access the file once they complete their payment and i am using paypal payment gateway,so i have applied the condition that the download link will only be visible to user once they have completed their transaction,but my requirement id this that user must not be able to open this zip file through url,but once they complete their transaction then the user can download the file from the link given by me 1.e 
[Download Zip](http://abc.com/rrrr/online1_files.zip), i have hosted my website on godaddy.

```
<?php
session_start();
 if(isset($_SESSION['item_name']) && $_SESSION['item_name']!=''){
     if($_SESSION['item_name']=='Android Apps'){
 ?>
 <a href="abc.com/rrr/online1_files.zip">Download Zip</a>
 <?php   } 
      } else{
             header('Location: abc.com/rrr/form1.html'); 
           } 
  ?>
```

Comment: Where is your code? Did you try anything?

Comment: please put some code. and dont forget to read the `about` in this page.

Comment: here is my code  <?php session_start();
 if(isset($_SESSION['item_name']) && $_SESSION['item_name']!=''){
  
 if($_SESSION['item_name']=='Android Apps'){?>
 <a href="http://www.abc.com/rrr/online1_files.zip">Download Zip</a>
 <?php 
 }
 }
 else{
header('Location: http://www.abc.com/rrr/form1.html');
}
?>

Answer (score 1):

use the following methods in your code. this way you don't need to redirect the user to the real url of zip file. you can serve the zip from any php script e.g. your payment confirmation page can redirect to a script with a random token which expires after first download/time-

```
//call this method for sending download file. 
function sendDL($filename)
{
    header("Content-length:".filesize($filename));
    header('Content-Type: application/x-gzip'); // ZIP file
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="download.gz"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    ob_end_clean(); //output buffer cleanup
    _readfileChunked($filename);
}

function _readfileChunked($filename, $retbytes=true) {
    $chunksize = 1*(1024*1024); // how many bytes per chunk
    $buffer = '';
    $cnt =0;
    // $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');
    if ($handle === false) {
        return false;
    }
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $buffer = fread($handle, $chunksize);
        echo $buffer;
        ob_flush();
        flush();
        if ($retbytes) {
            $cnt += strlen($buffer);
        }
    }
    $status = fclose($handle);
    if ($retbytes && $status) {
        return $cnt; // return num. bytes delivered like readfile() does.
    }
    return $status;
}
```

consider these like utility methods. from any script which doesn't push any other out (ie. no `echo`) the first method can be used for sending a file to user. call that like this

```
<?php

$dlToken = $_GET['dltoken'];
$filename = '/path/to/secret.file';

//Check if this dlToken is in database/memcache or not. and if yes its expired or not.


if($yes)
{
   sendDL($filename);
}
else
{
   sendNack();
}

function sendNack()
{
  echo '___DATA_NOT_FOUND___';  //NOTICE this is the only echo in this script. and it means we are not sending the file after all.
  //header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
  exit();
}

//put the two methods there

function sendDL($filename)
{
  //...
}

function _readfileChunked($filename, $retbytes=true) 
{
  //...
}

?>
```

At the page/script where you give the download link. generate a random unique token. you can use [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) or [mt_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) or both. save this in database along with a timestamp value (which you can use in download script mentioned above to check if the token has expired). create a download url with that token as something like following

```
download.php?file=test.zip&token=the_unique_token&timestamp=unix_timestamp
```

Comment: I not understand that from above code how can user download the zip file.